# PyQt - Fixed title for combobox

Tags: pyqt

I want to create a PyQt combobox with a fixed title. More specific this means that I want to have a dropdown menu from which the user can select but the dropdown button is always labeled the same. So for example I want to create an option for the user to specify where the legend of a plot is drawn. The button for this should always be labled "Legend" but when you click on it, it opens a dropdown menu with the placing options such as "upper right", "upper left", "top", etc. Once the user selected an option the legend is updated but the button still sais "Legend".
I have this so far:

```
    self.fnLegendButton = QtGui.QComboBox()
    self.fnLegendButton.addItems('Upper right,Lower right,Upper left,Lower left,Top,Disable'.split(','))
    self.fnLegendButton.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.fnLegendButton.setToolTip('Select the legend position.')
    self.fnLegendButton.currentIndexChanged.connect( <positioning function> )
    self.fnLegendButton.setMaximumWidth(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.fnLegendButton = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.fnLegendButton.addItems(
            'Legend,Upper right,Lower right,Upper left,Lower left,Top,Disable'.split(','))
        self.fnLegendButton.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.fnLegendButton.setToolTip('Select the legend position.')
        self.fnLegendButton.currentIndexChanged[
            str].connect(self.avoid_db_change)
        self.fnLegendButton.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.fnLegendButton.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
        self.show()

    def avoid_db_change(self, text):
        print("Processing {0} item".format(text))
        self.fnLegendButton.blockSignals(True)
        self.fnLegendButton.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.fnLegendButton.blockSignals(False)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The important bits of this code are inside the avoid_db_change, that function is the one used to keep the "Legend" text no matter which item you've pressed. Now, you don't want to fire that function again when `self.fnLegendButton.setCurrentIndex(0)` is executed, so to avoid that, you surround it by a couple of [blockSignals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) methods. Just try to comment the blockSignals methods and you'll understand what this means.

Comment: It would be nice if you could comment the code a bit.

Comment: @uitty400 Ok, I've edited my answer and added few comments about the relevant parts of the code

Answer (score 0):

old question but here is a better way without messing with signals.

```py
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)


    def addCheckableItem(self, item):
        super().addItem(item)
        item = self.model().item(self.count()-1,0)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

    def addTitleItem(self, item):
        super().addItem(item)
        # should be the first index in the combobox and not checkable or selectable
        item = self.model().item(0,0)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled)


    def itemChecked(self, index):
        item = self.model().item(index,0)
        return item.checkState() == Qt.Checked
    
    def checkedItems(self):
        return [self.itemText(i) for i in range(self.count()) if self.itemChecked(i)]
```

usage

```py
        combo = CheckableComboBox(self)
        combo.addTitleItem('some title')
        for item in items:
            combo.addCheckableItem(item)
```

this way all it does is tell pyqt, this is the first item, it should not be enabled for selection, manipulate to your own needs